# not allow 2 white space in text angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I use

```
    $scope.example = {
            word: /^\s*\w*\s*$/
          };
<input type="name" name="nameInput" placeholder="Name" required  ng-model="nameInput" ng-pattern="example.word" required ng-trim="false" ng-minlength="2">



    <span class="error" ng-show="contactForm.nameInput.$error.pattern " style="color: red"></span>
```

but not allow white space . How can I allow 1 space and not allow 2 space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean more than 1 spaces are not allowed, then you could use this regex::

```
/^(\w+\s)*\w+$/
```

Comment: cool , so i wanna not alow number and 2 white space , what can i do

Answer (score 1):

The usecase sound unusual, but I believe the follow regex would work: `/^\s?\w*\s?$/`

Answer (score 1):

I think `<input ng-pattern="/^(\w+\s)*\w+$/" />` is what you're looking for.